# I want to limit user referral to 1 referral per device

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a referral program for my software, the referral itself works with all the benefits attached to it, but I want it to work like if you share your referral link you shouldn't be able to open more than 1 account per device.

That is if open an account on my device that's it, any other account opened on that device shouldn't count. I am looking for a way to detect user or device IP so as to limit it to 1 per device, here is my middleware I am using to check for the referral at the point of registration.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    if (!$request->hasCookie('referral') && $request->query('ref')) {
        // Add a cookie to the response that lasts 5 years (in minutes)
        $response->cookie('referral', encrypt($request->query('ref')), 525600);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

and here is my registration controller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $referred_by = Cookie::get('referral');

    $user = '';

    $data['password'] = Hash::make($data['password']);

    $user = User::create($data);

    Wallet::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ]);
    Profile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'referral' => Str::random(5)
    ]);

    if ($referred_by != null) {
        $encrypter = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::class);
        $decryptedString = $encrypter->decrypt($referred_by);
        Referral::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'referred_by' =>  $decryptedString
        ]);
    }

    Mail::to($user)->send(new NewUserEmail($user));

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, this does not exist in a robust way and it would create big time privacy issues if you could do this in a reliable way across all devices.

Comment: well it is what the client wants, only 1 referral per device

Comment: Client can also ask for it to cast magic spells. This cant't be done reliably using ip, or device identifiers. You have no way to determine what devices a person owns. Not possible.

Comment: lolz, client are always funny you know

Comment: so which way can i achieve this if not perfect atleast to some extent

Comment: This feels like an x/y problem to me. What, specifically, is your client trying to achieve? You might be able to find a more elegant solution with more details about their goal. Perhaps a minimum amount of account activity to trigger referral benefits, if their goal is to prevent fake referrals.

Comment: so what the client wants to achieve is that you can not register more than 1 account on 1 device for referral tho u can open an account but it after the 1 it wont count as referral again!

Answer (score -1):

from what i know, php only gives 'User-Agent' header with browser info.

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$agent = $headers['User-Agent'];
```

For detailed information about user you need to use node js.

you can check GitHub, it has many projects related to user-device detection.

examples:

1. https://github.com/matomo-org/device-detector
2. https://github.com/keithws/browser-report

Comment: this only detects device type, not good for what i want